# How to translate "окающие и акающие, секающие и шекающие" correctly into English language?

Tags: перевод, выражения

I've tried versions like "retaining the unstressed “o” and “a”" and it seems to be wrong.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian SE. Unfortunately - and  if you take a look at your own question it will be quite obvious - this is not a question about Russian language and this renders it - and actually all "how this Russian term can be translated to English" questions - off-topic.

Comment: Окающие и акающие: speakers of the dialects without reduction of unstressed vowels o and a; those who speak with okanye (literally o-ing) and with akanye (literally a-ing). 

Check en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akanye

Actually it depends on the context where to use the translation: maybe, "those who speak rustic and old fashioned Slavic dialect" provides a sufficient sense and meaning of this phrase.